# How I can use variables in Adobe OSGI DDX Assembler like we are used in Livecycle ES4 DDX

Tags: osgi, adobe, workflow, aem, aem-6

We used workflow variables in DDX assembler with Livecycle ES4 JEE.
Like this:

```
<DDX xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/">
  <PDF result = "myPDF">
    <Watermark scale="70%" verticalOffset="-85pt" opacity="100%">
        <PDF source = "docLoteDeclaracoes" pages="{$/process_data/@intPagina$}"/>
    </Watermark>
    <PDF source = "docModeloAnexo"/>
  </PDF>
  <?ddx-source-hint name = "docLoteDeclaracoes"?>
  <?ddx-source-hint name = "docModeloAnexo"?>
</DDX>
```

In this code workflow process put value of page to be extracted from "docLoteDeclaracoes" in variable intPaginas.

I need to do similar thing using AEM Forms OSGI workflow, but this form to reference variables don't working.

Any one know how reference OSGI workflow variables in DDX document?

I am using AEM Forms 6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is other solution for this case.

1. Create one file with DDX commands.

```html
<DDX xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/">
  <PDF result = "doc.pdf">
        <PDF source = "docLoteDeclaracoes" pages="1"/>
  </PDF>
  <?ddx-source-hint name = "docLoteDeclaracoes"?>
</DDX>
```

2. Set one process variable type XML with file content.
   [image]
3. Update command XML Node with xpath for the content.
   XPath: //PDF[@source="docLoteDeclaracoes"]/@pages

[image]

4. Invoke DDX

[image]